# nested_forms adds 2 copies and deletes the first in Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: nested-forms, sprockets, nested-form-for, rails-3.1

Rails 3.1

[Nested_forms](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Ran into some issues setting up and might have [hacked the wrong solution together](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/108).

---

Any ideas on why...

- `link_to_add` is creating 2 copies
- `link_to_destroy` is destroying the wrong copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not related to Nested_forms, it was related to `rake assets:precompile`.  I was precompiling (unnecessarily) before pushing to Heroku which left me with two copies and strange jQuery behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.

I had included nested_form.js in my application layout file.

And I haven't changed my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file, it is as it is, when it was created at time of creating rails application.

When I removed entry from my application layout, problem was solved.